# Cannot create AKS cluster using ephemeral storage

Tags: azure-aks

I am trying to create an AKS cluster and would like to use ephemeral storage. I tried to create the cluster like this:

```
az aks create --name aks-example --resource-group example -s Standard_D2ds_v5 --node-osdisk-type Ephemeral --node-osdisk-size 70
```

The `D2ds_v5` size has a 75GiB temporary disk, so I would assume that this would work. My nodes run fairly simple images, so I guess I won't run into any issues. When I look at the the VM scaling set, then I see a node-pool with `D2ds_v5` instances, but it seems it connects an 70GB large Azure-storage backed HDD instead of using the local disk.

I also tried to use a `D4ds_v5` size (has 150GB local storage) and ran:

```
az aks create --name aks-example --resource-group example -s Standard_D4ds_v5 --node-osdisk-type Ephemeral
```

It now attached a 128GB large Azure-storage backed HDD.

Even the example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-create) don't work:

```
az aks create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyManagedCluster --node-osdisk-type Ephemeral --node-osdisk-size 48
```

It creates a 48GB large HDD. It seems it doesn't want to use the ephemeral disk. Anyone knows what's wrong? Using ephemeral disks is faster and also is cheaper when using 3-year reserved instances.

Comment: According to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2003), it's fine that the VM instance reports that a local HDD is used. It should be using the ephemeral storage.